# MLCP 9.0.8 fail to run log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I download/install MLCP 9.0.8 but it fail to run. How can I initialize the log4j system. Thanks in advance.

I have command lines in run-import.sh

/mlcp-9.0.8/bin/mlcp.sh IMPORT -options_file /output/import- 2018-2019/import-collection.txt

```
$ ./run-import.sh 
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger 
(com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.


$ cd /mlcp-9.0.8/conf 
$ ls -alt

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mklogic mklogic  538 Feb  1 11:21 log4j.properties
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 mklogic mklogic 3189 Dec 20 01:03 xcc.logging.properties

vi log4j.properties

log4j.rootLogger=INFO,console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
#log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n

# To suppress not native warn on Mac and Solaris
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client=ERROR

# To enable debug
log4j.logger.com.marklogic.mapreduce=DEBUG
log4j.logger.com.marklogic.contentpump=DEBUG
```

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `java --version` and `echo $JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: The only way that I am able to reproduce is to move/remove the log4j properties file, so that it can't be read from the `conf` dir. Have you tried invoking the `/mlcp-9.0.8/bin/mlcp.sh` directly?

Comment: Also, the user and group `mklogic` look suspicious. Is that correct, or should it be `marklogic`? What user are you running as, and are they in the `mklogic` group?

Comment: Thanks for all your helped.  I copied log4j.properties from MLCP version 8 into /mlcp-9.0.8/conf.  The problem solved.